# Java spark post parameteres not beign delivered

Tags: java, rest, curl

I have just started writing my first restAPI, I have decided to use Spark API.
But I have encountered a problem that I cant resolve.
I am trying to post some parameters e.g.

```
name - smth
```

I am using right now Postman and cURL:

```
curl -d "name=smth" http://localhost:8080/users
```

However neither from Postman nor cURL I cant get the parameter. Parameters on spark are still null. I have my route declared like

```
post(new Route("/users") {
    @Override
    public Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
        String s = (String) request.attribute("name");
        return s;
    }
});
```

Anyone has any idea what might be wrong?

Log from cURL:

```
== Info: About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
== Info:   Trying ::1...
== Info: connected
== Info: Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
=> Send header, 219 bytes (0xdb)
0000: POST /users HTTP/1.1
0016: User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0
0056:  OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.5
0072: Host: localhost:8080
0088: Accept: */*
0095: Content-Length: 9
00a8: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00d9: 
=> Send data, 9 bytes (0x9)
0000: item=smth
== Info: upload completely sent off: 9 out of 9 bytes
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 21 bytes (0x15)
0000: Content-Length: 105
<= Recv header, 32 bytes (0x20)
0000: Server: Jetty(9.0.2.v20130417)
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 105 bytes (0x69)
0000: <html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2>The requested route [/users] h
0040: as not been mapped in Spark</body></html>
== Info: Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
== Info: Closing connection #0
```

Comment: You can use `--trace-ascii curl.log` parameter to diagnose what curl is actually sending.

Comment: I think you may need a `-X POST` in the command to make sure you're using `POST`.

Comment: Are you sure it's `http://localhost:8080/users` and there's no root path before `users` part? Maybe start from some `GET` request, it should be easier to diagnose.

Comment: Get requests are working, post is working too, when I am not trying to access parameters

Comment: It's giving you a 404 - so the POST is not working. You need to fix that first.